# perl array to hash in map error as it says cant use id as strict refs is in use

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my @extensiveArray = ((
    id => 1,
    name => 'Bob',
    ),
    (
    id => 2,
    name => 'Barley',
    ),
    (
    id => 3,
name => 'Marley',
)
);


my %hashRef = map { $_->{id} => { $_->{name} } } @extensiveArray;
```

what is wrong in this code,it gives me error as "can't use string {id} as a HASH ref while 'strict refs' in use "

Comment: `@extensiveArray` is not what you think it is. `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \@extensiveArray;`

Comment: Also check where your array comes from - by any chance are you reading XML or JSON? Because there may be better solutions?

Comment: That code does not give that error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use hash references inside your `@extensiveArray`. What you have right now is a flat list. Perl does not support nested listed.

```
my @extensiveArray = (
    {
        id   => 1,
        name => 'Bob',
    },
    {
        id   => 2,
        name => 'Barley',
    },
    {
        id   => 3,
        name => 'Marley',
    }
);
```

Once you do that, you will get the error *Odd number of elements in anonymous hash*, because of the `{}`.

```
                                #    here    #
my %hashRef = map { $_->{id} => { $_->{name} } } @extensiveArray;
```

If you want to return a key/value pair from the `map`, just return a flat list. That's all a hash is, really.

```
my %hashRef = map { $_->{id} => $_->{name} } @extensiveArray;
```

You should check out [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and the other pages linked there.